# VSO Build vNext: Label on build and get by label

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to label the mapped source code to the build number in Visual Studio Online's Build vNext platform?  In XAML builds, one could "Label sources".

Furthermore, is it possible to get code by specific label or changeset once a new build has be triggered?

**EDIT:**

**Labeling on build is now available:**

[image: Labeling]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vNext build, the Label Sources feature is unavailable, and you can't specify to build with a specific label either. You can submit one feature request about it on Microsoft UserVoice site here:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30925-team-foundation-server-visual-studio-online

Comment: The link is dead. Also how can you have a build system where you cant select what version to build...?

Comment: No longer valid. Build by label is supported (enter source version **L**name). Label during build is now also supported.